# Hyphenation in classicthesis graffito

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation, classicthesis

I am using the `classicthesis` package and the `graffito` side notes it provides. However, I'd like those side notes to be properly hyphenated, even though I think they were not intended to be by the author. I tried to adjust the definition of `graffito` to hyphenate, but to no avail. How should this be done?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

% graffito definition, modified to change hyphenation penalties
\makeatletter
\def\graffito@setup{%
   \slshape\footnotesize% 
   \parindent=0pt \lineskip=0pt \lineskiplimit=0pt %
   \tolerance=2000
   \hyphenpenalty=0 % was 300
   \exhyphenpenalty=0 % was 300
   \doublehyphendemerits=100000% 
   \finalhyphendemerits=\doublehyphendemerits
   }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\graffito{Text with extremely excessively unnecessarily long words which unfortunately,
undesiredly and awkwardly are not being hyphenated.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\graffito` definition includes (after `\graffito@setup`) `\raggedleft`/`\raggedright`; this must be replaced with `\RaggedLeft`/`\RaggedRight` (from the [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package) to allow hyphenation. For convenience, I use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to do so.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage {ragged2e}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\graffito}{\raggedright}{\RaggedRight}{}{}
\patchcmd{\graffito}{\raggedleft}{\RaggedLeft}{}{}

\begin{document}
\graffito{Text with extremely excessively unnecessarily long words which unfortunately,
undesiredly and awkwardly are not being hyphenated.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably have to do the same with `\raggedleft` changed into `\RaggedLeft`, for marginpars in even numbered pages.

Comment: You can ease things by loading the `ragged2e` package with the option `newcommands`. That way, the instructions `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright` inside the `\graffito` command will be redefined to act like `\RaggedLeft` and `\RaggedRight`.